# What can cause a C variable to be initialized on 1?

Tags: c, gcc, operating-system, nasm

I am making a basic x86 operating system with a group using C and NASM for college. We have to make a simple game using VGA Mode 3 to display the 'graphics' on a 80x50 characters grid. We are using bochs to simulate the OS.

Some time ago we had to make a procedure that, whenever a key is pressed, displays it on the top right of the screen. The teachers gave us some pre-made functions to interact with the PIC, and map the keyboard interrupt to entry 33 on the IDT. We had no problem with the implementation.

Now, recently, we added functionality to the necesary keys, while still displaying the pressed key on the top right. The difference is that now, for some reason, whenever you release the key, or press another one (i.e. you generate a scan code that isn't for a key that does something in-game), a smiley face is printed on the top right.

This is the code for the interrupt handler for the keyboard:

```nasm
global _isr33

_isr33:
pushad
    xor eax,eax
    in al, 0x60
    push eax
    call manejo_teclado
    pop eax
    call fin_intr_pic1
popad
iret
```

This is the 'manejo_teclado' (handle_keyboard):

```c
char manejo_teclado(char scanCode){
    char valor;
    int player;
    direccion dir;

    if(scanCode == 0x2a){ 
        valor = '1';

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x36){
        valor = '2'; 

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x1f){
        valor = 's'; 
        dir = ABA;
        player = 0;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    //1e (A), 1f (S), 20 
    if(scanCode == 0x1e){
        valor = 'a';
        dir = IZQ;
        player = 0;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x20){
        valor = 'd';
        dir = DER;
        player = 0;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x11){
        valor = 'w';
        dir = ARB;
        player = 0;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    //24 (J), 25 (K), 26 (L)
    if(scanCode ==0x17 ){
        valor = 'i';
        dir = ARB;
        player = 1;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x24){
        valor = 'j';
        dir = IZQ;
        player = 1;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x25){
        valor ='k' ;
        dir = ABA;
        player = 1;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);

    }
    if(scanCode == 0x26 ){
        valor = 'l';
        dir = DER;
        player = 1;
        game_mover_cursor(player,dir);          
    }
    if(scanCode == 0x15){
        //modo debug
        valor = 'y';
        //lanzar_modo_debug();
    }

    print_char(valor, 79, 0, (unsigned short)0x0E);
    return valor;
}
```

And the 'print_char' (VIDEO_SCREEN is 0xB8000 and 'ca' is a struct that holds a byte for character and a byte for formatting)

```
void print_char(char  text, unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned short attr) {
    ca (*p)[VIDEO_COLS] = (ca (*)[VIDEO_COLS]) VIDEO_SCREEN;
    p[y][x].c = (unsigned char) text;
    p[y][x].a = (unsigned char) attr; 
}
```

The 'valor' variable, that is the one that gets printed to the screen, is never initialized when the scanCode isn't one of the defined ones, but still is being initialized with the value of 1 (the code for the face).

I have changed the 'manejo_teclado' function, replacing the chain of ifs for a single if-else if-else if-.. chain. This gets rid of the smiley face.

The face is also consistent, it has happened on all the computers we have compiled this in. We didn't make the makefile (teachers provided one for us), and the gcc version is 4.8.4.

So for the questions: Is this something that is caused by the compiling process? Is gcc misinterpreting something on the function? Are we missing something else?

Sorry for any typos and/or mistakes, here's a pic of the perpetrator:

[image: The perpetrator]

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Unrelated to your question and your problem, but interrupts needs to be *quick*. They should do as little as possible, if possible just save relevant data and set a flag indicating that the interrupt has happened. Then let the operating system on the next tick (or the program main loop if running without an interrupt) check for the flag and perform whatever needs to be done.

Comment: If you're wondering why an uninitialized stack variable has a certain value, it probably comes from the stack of a previously called function that used that same memory. You obviously can't rely on its value.

Comment: There is no `else` clause after all the `if` statements. So if a scan code comes which you didn't test for, `char valor;` is uninitialised --> *undefined behaviour*. Initialise `char valor = 0;` when you declare it, and ignore that value if still there. Nobody can explain why the value is 1, and you can't rely on that if you have not explicitly set it. And as commented *never* call a high level output routine from interrupt.

Comment: I forgot that C functions use variables from the stack. You are right that it is undefined behavior, but the question was more aimed at why was it taking the value 1 every time. This function is using the kernel stack, so the value must be coming from the scheduler, wich is, at that point, the only other procedure being called at kernel privilege level.

Comment: C does not "use variables from the stack". C has the concept of storage/lifetime, and block-scoped objects that are not declared with the storage-class specifier "static" have **automatic storage duration**. Whether this is implemented as a stack is irrelevant.